# All plane curves that satisfy some conditions

Tags: calculus

> "Find all plane curves in the first quadrant such that for every point
>   $P$ on the curve, $P$ bisects the part of the tangent line at $P$ that lies
>   in the first quadrant."

I found that the tangent line at $P$ must intersect the positive $x$- and $y$-axes. Also, the slope of the tangent at such a point is necessarily negative. Let the slope at this $P(x_0,y_0)$ is $m$ so that the tangent line is given by $$y-y_0=m(x-x_0).$$
I know how to find the $x$- and $y$-intercepts of this line but I can't manage to get anything after finding them, I appreciate any help, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ be $(x,y)$, The eq. of atangent at P is
$$Y-y=m (X-x), m=\frac{dy}{dx}$$
The co-ordinates of the points of intersction at x and y axis are
$A(x-y/m,0), B(0,y-mx)$, the mid point of $AB$ is $P$ so we have
$$x=\frac{x-y/m}{2} \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{y}{x} \implies \int \frac{dy}{y}=- \int \frac{dx}{x} \implies \ln y=-\ln x+\ln C \implies xy=C$$
All such curves rectangular hyperbolas: $xy=C$

Comment: Thank you for the explanations, I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* Since the line is the tangent line to the curve $y=f(x)$ at the point $(x_0,y_0),$ then it follows that $m=f'(x_0)=\mathrm dy/\mathrm dx|_{x=x_0}.$ Also, at each point $(x_0,y_0),$ the distance between this point and the intercepts on the axes must be equal. From these two equations you get your differential equation, which you solve.